# Excel - Copy Conditional Formatting, Remove Rules, Keep Format

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I know you usually show what you've tried in a question, but this is more of a "Do you have a good routine that does this?" question and I'm hoping you'll be willing to let it slide...

I'm working on a macro that copies cells that are conditionally formatted in a source worksheet and pastes them into an output sheet.
Basically, I'm looking to keep all the formatting, shading, etc, but remove all the conditions (make the current formatting static) in the output sheet.

I've seen some solutions online - ranging from copying it first to a word document and then pasting it back, to looping through the output cells and copying format-element by format-element - and am just looking for a good, efficient way to do this.

Does anyone have one / a good link they'd be willing to share??

(Excel 2010)

THANKS!!!!

Comment: + 1 `I know you usually show what you've tried i...` And I usually do not answer questions which has not shown some efforts but this is a good question :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes it is possible :) What you need to do is change the formatting of the cells that you plan to copy by mimicking the `DisplayFormat` and then deleting the conditional formatting

```
Sub Keep_Format()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim mySel As Range, aCell As Range

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    '~~> Change this to the relevant range
    Set mySel = ws.Range("A1:A10")

    For Each aCell In mySel
        With aCell
          .Font.FontStyle = .DisplayFormat.Font.FontStyle
          .Interior.Color = .DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
          .Font.Strikethrough = .DisplayFormat.Font.Strikethrough
        End With
    Next aCell

    mySel.FormatConditions.Delete

    '
    '~~> Now Do the copying
    '

    '~~> Once you are done, close the sorce worksheet without saving
End Sub
```

Comment: An awesomely coded and elegant solution! - No frills, no fuss!! !!!PERFECT AND THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Is there a way of reapplying the conditional formatting? What I want to do is to remove the conditional formatting, copy and paste the cells in a different sheet, then reapply the conditional formatting. Can this be done?

Comment: This little gem just saved so much time. I've been trying to find a way around leaving a conditional formatting formula applied to 15000+ cell column and this is just perfect. Thank you ! +1

Comment: unfortunately this does not work with borders and border line styles. Otherwise good job

Comment: a **more complete copy routine** can be found here (also copying borders e.g.): https://stackoverflow.com/a/56036633/1915920

Answer (score 9):

I think I've got it with the Office Clipboard: Copy range, open the Office Clipboard pane (the tiny button in the bottom right corner of the Clipboard section under the Home tab) and paste from there.

Here's a demo: http://www.bookkempt.com/2017/08/remove-conditional-formatting-but-keep.html

Comment: OH WOW.  How is this not the correct answer!?  This is the only place where anyone has said this, and this is the easiest, non-VBA way to paste formatting.

Comment: Thanks, I came across this fidgeting with the office clipboard. I couldn't find anything elsewhere either.

Comment: this was much simpler

Answer (score 2):

I copied my range of cells. Pasted them into Word. Recopied the range in Word and pasted back into excel.

Comment: definitely the easiest

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to do the same, all answers seemed too much of work for me or based on some bug / glitch.

What worked for me is opening `ms word` copying the whole table from `ms excel` into `ms word` then pasting it back to `ms excel`. The style is there but the conditional formatting doesn't apply anymore.

Answer (score -1):

A very simple method is to filter the list by color.  Then FILL with the appropriate cell color you need.  then unfilter and remove conditional formatting.  The fill will remain.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.