# Pasting Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy the values and conditional formatting from a column in the sheet `wsHR` and paste them into `wsHH`.

With the code below the values are pasted, but the formatting is not.

I added formatting into `wsHR` that isn't conditional, and it works fine copying that over.

Is there a way to paste conditional formatting?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Set variables
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim wsHR As Worksheet
Dim wsHH As Worksheet
Dim y As Integer

'Set row value
y = 4

'Set heavy chain raw data worksheet
Set wsHR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(4)
'Set heavy chain hits worksheet
Set wsHH = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(6)

'Optimizes Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Finds last row
With wsHR
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

'Iterates through rows in column A, and copies the row into proper sheet depending on "X" in PBS/KREBS
For i = 4 To LastRow
    'Checks for "X" in PBS
    If VarType(wsHR.Range("AD" & i)) = 8 Then
        If wsHR.Range("AD" & i).Value = "X" Or wsHR.Range("AE" & i).Value = "X" Then
            With wsHH
                wsHR.Range("A" & i).Copy
                .Range("A" & y).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                .Range("A" & y).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                'Range before PBS/KREBS
                .Range("B" & y & ":AC" & y).Value = wsHR.Range("B" & i & ":AC" & i).Value
                'Adds space to keep formulas for PBS/KREBS
                'Range after PBS/KREBS
                .Range("AG" & y & ":AW" & y).Value = wsHR.Range("AG" & i & ":AW" & i).Value
            End With
            y = y + 1
        End If
    End If
Next i

'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "Complete"

'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I cannot use the same conditional formatting rules in the second sheet, `wsHH`, because not all of the values from `wsHR` are pasted. The conditional formatting is based on duplicates.

Comment: So you want conditional formatting in wsHH based on conditions in wsHR?

Comment: @OldUgly I was originally trying to copy the formatting from cells which were conditionally formatted not realizing the information for conditional formatting is stored separately. After a lot of looking around I came to the solution I've put as an answer below.

Comment: Glad you found a way to get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a work-around to get the formatting. Previously, you were not able to access the interior color from conditional formatting in VBA without going through a lot of extra work ([see here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/cfcolors.htm)). However, I discovered as of Excel 2010, this was changed ([see here](http://www.excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/338-Get-Displayed-Cell-Color-(whether-from-Conditional-Formatting-or-not)/page2)). Since I'm using Excel 2013, I am able to use `.DisplayFormat` to find the interior color regardless of formatting ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838814.aspx)).

Using this, I changed:

```
With wsHH
  wsHR.Range("A" & i).Copy
  .Range("A" & y).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
  .Range("A" & y).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
  'Range before PBS/KREBS
  .Range("B" & y & ":AC" & y).Value = wsHR.Range("B" & i & ":AC" & i).Value
  'Adds space to keep formulas for PBS/KREBS
  'Range after PBS/KREBS
  .Range("AG" & y & ":AW" & y).Value = wsHR.Range("AG" & i & ":AW" & i).Value
End With
```

to this:

```
With wsHH
  'Range before PBS/KREBS
  .Range("A" & y & ":AC" & y).Value = wsHR.Range("A" & i & ":AC" & i).Value
  'Adds space to keep formulas for PBS/KREBS
  'Applying background CF color to new sheet
  If wsHR.Range("A" & i).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex > 0 Then
    .Range("A" & y).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
  End If
  'Range after PBS/KREBS
  .Range("AG" & y & ":AW" & y).Value = wsHR.Range("AG" & i & ":AW" & i).Value
End With
```

I am no longer copying and pasting values. Instead, I set the values using `.Value` like I had been for the other cells in the row, and then use the outcome of `If wsHR.Range("A" & i).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex > 0 Then` to determine if the second sheet's cell should be formatted.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some more complete and customizable/parameterized copy subs to complete this task in a quite performant way. So one can decide if things like the following should be copied or not:

- border styles
- font styles
- background color (foreground is always copied)
- text wrapping
- horizontal and/or vertical alignment
- normal paste operation with its `XlPasteType` and `XlPasteSpecialOperation` params

  - by default enabled and copying the values and number formats
  - which would not copy conditional formatting styles applied

## general example usage of custom subs below

e.g. the following call:

```
EventsDisable
PasteWithDisplayFormat Range("B40"), Range("A1:Z30")
EventsEnable
```

## OP query example

in the OP example it should be something like this:

```
With wsHH
  PasteWithDisplayFormat .Range("A" & y), wsHR.Range("A" & i)
  '...
End With
```

instead of:

```
With wsHH
  wsHR.Range("A" & i).Copy
  .Range("A" & y).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
  .Range("A" & y).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
  '...
End With
```

## custom subs

(please feel free to enhance/extend it here for others)

```
'including conditional formatting as fixed styles (DisplayFormat)
'based on Range.PasteSpecial
Public Sub PasteWithDisplayFormat( _
    dst As Range, _
    Optional src As Range, _
    Optional pasteSpecialBefore As Boolean = True, _
    Optional paste As XlPasteType = xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
    Optional Operation As XlPasteSpecialOperation = xlNone, _
    Optional SkipBlanks As Boolean = False, _
    Optional Transpose As Boolean = False, _
    Optional Borders As Boolean = True, _
    Optional Font As Boolean = True, _
    Optional InteriorColor As Boolean = True, _
    Optional WrapText As Boolean = True, _
    Optional HorizontalAlignment As Boolean = True, _
    Optional VerticalAlignment As Boolean = True _
    )

    If src Is Nothing Then Set src = Selection

    If pasteSpecialBefore Then dst.PasteSpecial paste:=paste, Operation:=Operation, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Dim x As Integer:  For x = 1 To src.Rows.Count
        For y = 1 To src.Columns.Count
            Dim sf As DisplayFormat:  Set sf = src.Cells(x, y).DisplayFormat  'source cells DisplayFormat

            With dst.Cells(x, y)
                If Borders Then CopyBorders .Borders, sf.Borders

                If Font Then
                    .Font.ColorIndex = sf.Font.ColorIndex
                    .Font.Color = sf.Font.Color
                    .Font.Background = sf.Font.Background
                    .Font.FontStyle = sf.Font.FontStyle  '=> bold + italic
                    '.Font.Bold = sf.Font.Bold
                    '.Font.Italic = sf.Font.Italic
                    .Font.Size = sf.Font.Size
                    .Font.Name = sf.Font.Name
                End If
                If InteriorColor Then .Interior.Color = sf.Interior.Color
                If WrapText Then .WrapText = sf.WrapText
                If HorizontalAlignment Then .HorizontalAlignment = sf.HorizontalAlignment
                If VerticalAlignment Then .VerticalAlignment = sf.VerticalAlignment
            End With
        Next y
    Next x

End Sub


Sub CopyBorders(dst As Borders, src As Borders)
    If src.LineStyle <> xlLineStyleNone Then
        dst.ColorIndex = src.ColorIndex
        If src.ColorIndex <> 0 Then dst.Color = src.Color
        dst.Weight = src.Weight
        dst.LineStyle = src.LineStyle
        dst.TintAndShade = src.TintAndShade
    End If
    Dim bi As Integer:  For bi = 1 To src.Count  'border index
        CopyBorder dst(bi), src(bi)
    Next bi
End Sub


Sub CopyBorder(dst As Border, src As Border)
    If src.LineStyle <> xlLineStyleNone Then
        dst.ColorIndex = src.ColorIndex
        If src.ColorIndex <> 0 Then dst.Color = src.Color
        dst.Weight = src.Weight
        dst.LineStyle = src.LineStyle
        dst.TintAndShade = src.TintAndShade
    End If
End Sub


'used with EventsEnable()
Sub EventsDisable()
    With Application: .EnableEvents = False:  .ScreenUpdating = False:  .Calculation = xlCalculationManual:  End With
End Sub


'used with EventsDisable()
Sub EventsEnable()
    With Application:  .EnableEvents = True:  .ScreenUpdating = True:  .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic:  End With
End Sub
```

## Other approaches found

### temp MS Word doc approach

here is one example **based on copying to a temp word file and pasting back**, but (at least on more complex tables) results in the pasting of some **OLE embedded object** that is not really usable in excel anymore, but could suffice for other uses:

https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/119606-copy-colors-but-not-conditional-formating?p=1059236#post1059236

### xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats

using `xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats` as the `XlPasteType` seems to produce the same result like the *temp MS Word doc* approach above