# Excel VBA Remove Conditional formatting keep borders

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I have found a [thread where the conditional formatting is removed but the format is kept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768023/excel-copy-conditional-formatting-remove-rules-keep-format).

If I run the script I am losing the conditional formatting of the borders. Is it also possible to keep all information on the border?

Best,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `With aCell` block, you can try adding this:

```
Dim b as long
For b = 1 To 12
  .Borders(b).LineStyle = .DisplayFormat.Borders(b).LineStyle
  .Borders(b).Color = .DisplayFormat.Borders(b).Color
  .Borders(b).Weight = .DisplayFormat.Borders(b).Weight
Next
```

p.s. I used numeric values for the enumeration `xlEdgeTop`, `xlEdgeLeft` etc..., to shorten the code with a loop.