# Excel 2016 Copy only conditional format cell color from range (G4:G100) to (E4:E100)

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting, excel-2016

Afternoon,

I have a drop down list in my budget sheet from G4:G100 with conditional formatting to change cell colour according to text from drop down.

What I cant seem to do is link cells in range E4:E100 to have same cell colour as  in G4:G100?

[image: IMG1]

I have tried to use in VBA:

```
Sub Copy_Color()
    Dim iColor As Long
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 4 To 100
        iColor = Worksheets("Sheet15").Range("G" & i).Interior.Color
        Worksheets("Sheet15").Range("E" & i).Interior.Color = iColor
    Next
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel - Copy Conditional Formatting, Remove Rules, Keep Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768023/excel-copy-conditional-formatting-remove-rules-keep-format)

Comment: I don't get the actual problem. However, if you want to get to conditional format colors, you need to use 
    Worksheets("Sheet15").Range("G" & i).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color

Comment: I would like just the color of G4 to G100, which is chosen by conditional formatting to be duplicated in E4 to E100

Comment: Just the color as this range E4 to E100 will contain numbers

Answer (score 1):

I've updated this to hopefully make the options clearer.

**Option 1:** using a routine you have to call manually. This answers your question literally ...

```
Public Sub CopyColor()
    Range("G4:G100").Copy
    Range("E4:E100").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End Sub
```

**Option 2:** (my preferred option for you). You can setup your conditional formatting from column G to include column E in the same conditional format. Select ranges G4:G100 AND E4:E100 and create a condition format with your rules and color formatting, noting that you use $ on column G to force the condition format to always work from that column. For example:

```
=IF($G4="Bank",TRUE,FALSE)
```

**Option 3:** you could use the following code so that any time a cell is updated in the worksheet, it copies the formatting from G4:G100 to E4:E100.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("G4:G100").Copy
    Range("E4:E100").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

(I'm not sure of your sheet name, but add to your sheet like this ...)

[image]

Comment: I just wanted an automated flow

Comment: Hi John. I've updated my answer. Hope this is clearer in terms of the options and what each provides.