# Copy formatting only from range with conditional formatting, without the conditions

Tags: excel, formatting

I am doing something like a heatmap. I have data that I'm summarizing in a pivot table and first I am doing the heatmap with conditional formatting with 3-color scale (lowest to highest) based on the values shown as percentages of the grand total. This part works just fine and I get the heatmap.

[image: this is the heatmap with the % values]

But I then want to copy the formatting only and paste the actual values on top (not the percentages) so I can illustrate the volumes of each cell. How do I copy the formatting only from the range without also getting the conditions?

In the attached image, imagine that I want the original values instead of the percentages. But in order to do that, I need to copy/paste the formatting only. (because the percentages are actually a formula themselves and I can't just apply the conditional formatting on the values)

Hope my explanation makes sense :)

Comment: Not to me.  Instead of asking us to imagine what you want, why not just show us?  And why do you think you cannot apply conditional formatting on the values?  What is the difference between the values, and the results we see in the cells?.

Comment: The conditional formatting is done on data after some manipulation. I want to then have as cell contents the actual values. If I apply the conditional formatting on the values, it will result in different formatting. I figured out a workaround with copy/pasting the original table in Word, then it loses the conditions and I can copy/paste it back in excel, delete the values and paste the ones I want.

Comment: So your problem is how to copy the formatting, without copying the rules. The other information in your question is not relevant to your problem.  If that is the case, then see [Excel - Copy Conditional Formatting, Remove Rules, Keep Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768023/excel-copy-conditional-formatting-remove-rules-keep-format)

Comment: That would do the trick, thanks @RonRosenfeld

Comment: Since that is what you want, I will mark this as a duplicate. That way, others who happen upon this will get directed to a usable answer.